# Preventing Crawlers (Google in particular), from crawling a certain folder in my domain?

Tags: .htaccess, seo, robots.txt, googlebot

I'm looking for an advice and the method to so;
I have a folder on my domain where I am testing a certain landing page;
If it goes well I'll might build a new website and domain with this landing page,
and that's the main reasons I don't want it to get crawled, so I won't be punished by Google for duplicate content. I also don't want unwanted bots to scrape this landing page, as no good can come out of it. does it make sense to you?

If so, how can I do this? I don't think robots.txt is the best method as I understood that not all crawlers respect it, and even google may not fully respect it. I can't put a password since the landing page should be open to all humans (so the solution must not cause any problem to human visitors). does it leave the .htaccess file? If so, what code should I add there? are there any downsides I didn't get?

Thanks!

Comment: Robots.txt is your best bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**`robots.txt`**](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) file with following content:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /some-folder/
```

Comment: 1) what about crawlers that don't respect the file?
2) would it be even better If I include in each page this line:
     <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />

Comment: You can actually do that too OR use mod_rewrite rules to block known crawlers.

Comment: What's the main difference between the mod_rewrite and using the robots?

Comment: Actually `robots.txt` is preferred way and all standard search bots respect that.

Comment: `mod_rewrite` is forceful way of blocking/allowing certain properties of a web request such as search agent etc.

Comment: Please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.